# How can I display an overlay in Mozilla Thunderbird 52 within the email composer?

Tags: javascript, overlay, mozilla, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm building a timer that will show how long you've spent writing an email, but so far have only gotten it to show up at the bottom of the main screen. The timer works fine, but I haven't found the right path to overlay on the composer window, not the main screen.

The path it currently follows is this:

```
overlay chrome://messenger/content/messenger.xul chrome://myfirstext/content/myhelloworld.xul
```

myhelloworld.xul then points it to the timer overlay.

Thanks!